# calling method in mainactivity from another class in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-mediaplayer

I have a list view with text view and three image buttons. I'm trying to call a method from the main page when one of the image buttons is clicked. But I got this error:

```
  04-19 13:02:48.021 30996-30996/com.example.lama.audiotest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.lama.audiotest, PID: 30996
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:92)
                                                                            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
                                                                            at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:1007)
                                                                            at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:990)
                                                                            at com.example.lama.audiotest.Main3Activity.play(Main3Activity.java:35)
                                                                            at com.example.lama.audiotest.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:83)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I tried moving this line:

```
mp= MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this,R.raw.alfatiha);
```

to the onCreate(); and then it worked, but I want to play different audio depending on the string I got with the play method. how to solve this?

my mainactivity:

```
public class Main3Activity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = Main3Activity.class.getSimpleName();
static MediaPlayer mp;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();

    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

}

public void play(String name){
    if (name.equals("الفاتحه")){
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this,R.raw.alfatiha);
        mp.start();
    }
}

public void pause(){
        mp.pause();
}

public void stop(){
    mp.stop();
}
}
```

my list adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Main3Activity  main= new Main3Activity();
private static final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;

public CustomAdapter() {
    listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>(5);
    listArray.add(new DataModel("الفاتحه", 5, 1.8, "Java"));
    listArray.add(new DataModel("البقرة", 10, 2.8, "Python"));
    listArray.add(new DataModel("ال عمران", 15, 3.8, "Django"));

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listArray.size();    // total number of elements in the list
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return listArray.get(i);    // single item in the list
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;                   // index number
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
    }

    final MediaPlayer mp;


    final DataModel dataModel = listArray.get(index);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Itemname);
    textView.setText(dataModel.getName());

    ImageButton play = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
    ImageButton pause = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnpause);
    ImageButton stop = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnstop);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            main.play(dataModel.getName());
           // Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "you clicked play for: " + dataModel.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            main.pause();

          //  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "you clicked pause for: " + dataModel.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            main.stop();
          //  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "you clicked stop for: " + dataModel.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "string: " + dataModel.getName());
            Log.d(TAG, "int: " + dataModel.getAnInt());
            Log.d(TAG, "double: " + dataModel.getaDouble());
            Log.d(TAG, "otherData: " + dataModel.getOtherData());

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: " + dataModel.getOtherData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CustomAdapter you are creating a new instance of Main3Activity instead of passing your current Main3Activity instance as an argument for your Custom adapter. Because of that, your are getting a null pointer exeception when you are trying to access to Main3Activity methods.

To solve your problem modify your CustomAdapter constructor to allow Main3Activity as argument:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Main3Activity  main;
    private static final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;

    public CustomAdapter(Main3Activity main) {
        this.main = main;
        listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>(5);
        listArray.add(new DataModel("الفاتحه", 5, 1.8, "Java"));
        listArray.add(new DataModel("البقرة", 10, 2.8, "Python"));
        listArray.add(new DataModel("ال عمران", 15, 3.8, "Django"));
    }
```

Then, back into your Main3Activity.class, pass activity instance to CustomAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to reference the outer class from the adapter.

I assume that the adapter is defined inside the Activity class.
Then all you need to do is call the method directly with no prefix and it will find it.

Alternatively, for clarity, you can use:

```
Main3Activity.this.play(xxxx)
```

inside the onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class you are creating a new instance of Main3Activity which is different instance that's why you are getting NullPointerException. All you need to do is given below.

create an interface inside your adapter class.

```
public interface ItemActionListener{
         void onpause(DataModel model);
        void onStop(DataModel model);
        void onPlay(DataModel model);
    }
private ItemActionListener onItemActionlListener;
```

Create a setter for this interface

```
 public void setOnItemActionlListener(ItemActionListener onItemActionlListener) {
            this.onItemActionlListener = onItemActionlListener;
        }
```

Use this interface in your activity class like below.

```
  CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    customAdapter.setOnItemActionlListener(onItemActionListener);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


 private CustomAdapter .ItemActionListener onItemActionListener=new CustomAdapter .ItemActionListener() {


        @Override
        public void onpause(DataModel model) {
          //Call your pause() method written in activity class
          pause();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStop(DataModel model) {
             //Call your stop() method written in activity class
          stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlay(DataModel model) {
  //Call your play() method written in activity class
          play();
        }
    };




In your adapter class

 pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(onItemActionlListener !=null){
                onItemActionlListener.onpause(dataModel);

                 }



            }
        });
```